# React simple data manager

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I'm doing a react project.
Until now, i've stored data meant to circulate between unrelated components with LocalStorage.setItem and .getItem. However, the new type of data i have to work with is too big.

I've tried to implement redux, but it don't understand everything and changing every file to use it would take so long. Is there a simple manager that works like localStorage but with more space ? Thank you

Comment: Is mongo (quite simple) or postgres an option for you?

Comment: I haven't thought about using an external db, thank you. I know how to use mysql

Comment: Doesn't neccessarily need to be external, you can run postgresql locally with your node or install mongo via npm..

Comment: Oh really ? Thank you, i'll look more into it

Comment: It's a pleasure ;)